# Spring R2DBC query by example with projected/custom entity

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

The title maybe is not properly written but here is what, more or less, I want to achieve.

I would like to be able to write dynamic queries with use of [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/#r2dbc.repositories.queries.query-by-example) that would join multiple tables and create ([projection?](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos)) DTO for me.
This DTO would have fields that are mapped to different columns in joined tables. Consider following:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE address
(
    id                 SERIAL,
    address_code       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    street_name        VARCHAR(255),
    building_number    VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE account
(
    id                     SERIAL,
    account_number         BIGINT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE customer
(
    id                     SERIAL,
    name         VARCHAR(255)
)
```

I would like to be able to create a query which result would be:

`address.address_code`, `account.account_number`, `customer.name`

so basically the result would be a custom DTO. I also mentioned that I would like to have this backed up with `Query by Example` because I will to dynamically append `WHERE` clauses so I thought that if I created a DTO like:

```
public record CustomQueryResultDTO(String addressCode, BigInteger accountNumber, String name) {}
```

I could simply query just like it is in [Spring R2DBC documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/#r2dbc.repositories.queries.query-by-example).

The problem here is that I am not sure what should be a viable solution for such problem because on one hand I would like to reuse `ReactiveQueryByExampleExecutor` but that would mean that I have to create something like:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomQueryResultRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<CustomQueryResultDTO, Integer>, ReactiveQueryByExampleExecutor<CustomQueryResultDTO> {
}
```

Which kind of seems to me not a way to go as I do not have a corresponding table for `CustomQueryResultDTO` therefore there is really no mapping for this repository interface - or am I overthinking this and it is actually a way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are potentially overthinking it.

You can do it in a number of ways (note Java 17 text blocks):

- Via R2DBC JPA-like `@Query`

  - Create a normal `ReactiveCrudRepository` but collect into a projection (DTOP)

```java
// Repository
@Repository
public interface UserRefreshTokenRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<UserRefreshToken, Integer> {
  @Query(
    """
    select *
      from user.user_refresh_tokens t
        join user.user_infos c on c.user_id = t.user_id
        where c.username = :username
    """
  )
  Flux<UserRefreshTokenDtop> findAllByUsername(String username);
}

// Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = {"refreshToken"})
@Table(schema = "user", name = "user_refresh_tokens")
public class UserRefreshToken {
  @Id private Integer id;
  private String userId;
  private String username; # will be joined
  private String ipAddr;
  private OffsetDateTime createdAt;
  private String refreshToken;
  private OffsetDateTime refreshTokenIat;
  private OffsetDateTime refreshTokenExp;
}

// DTO projection
public interface UserRefreshTokenDtop {
  Integer getId();

  String getUserId();

  String getUsername(); # will be joined

  String getIpAddr();

  OffsetDateTime getRefreshTokenIat();

  OffsetDateTime getRefreshTokenExp();
}
```

- Via `DatabaseClient`

  - This one also uses `TransactionalOperator` to ensure query atomicity

```java
private final DatabaseClient client;
private final TransactionalOperator operator;

@Override
public void deleteAllUsedExpiredAttempts(Duration resetInterval) {
  // language=PostgreSQL
  String allUsedExpiredAttempts = """
         select t.id failed_id, c.id disable_id, t.username
           from user.failed_sign_attempts t
             join user.disable_sign_attempts c on c.username = t.username
           where c.is_used = true
             and :now >= c.expires_at + interval '%d seconds'
          """;

  // POTENTIAL SQL injection - half-arsed but %d ensures that only Number is allowed
  client
      .sql(String.format(allUsedExpiredAttempts, resetInterval.getSeconds()))
      .bind("now", Instant.now())
      .fetch()
      .all()
      .flatMap(this::deleteFailed)
      .flatMap(this::deleteDisabled)
      .as(operator::transactional)
      .subscribe(v1 -> log.debug("Successfully reset {} user(s)", v1));
}
```

- Via `R2dbcEntityTemplate`

  - I don't have a working example but it is pain in the ass to join via the `.join()` operator
  - If you are interested check the docs for `R2dbcEntityTemplate`

    - 13.4.3. Fluent API > Methods for the Criteria Class
    - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html